# install4j application uses wrong proxy setting

Tags: install4j

I'm using these settings in install4j.vmoptions (install4j 7.0.4):

```
# Clear out cached proxy information
-Dinstall4j.clearProxyCache=true
# and hopefully prevent install4j from reloading it from the default browser
-Dinstall4j.noProxyAutoDetect=true
# Unconditionally shows proxy config dialog
-Dinstall4j.showProxyConfig=true
# Log issues to %TEMP%\install4j_error.log
-Dinstall4j.showConnectError=true
```

I do not get a proxy dialog; the output in the error log is this:

```
java.io.IOException: Proxy password required. Please set the parameter -DproxyAuthPassword=[password].
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.HttpRequestHandler.askForProxyPassword(HttpRequestHandler.java:335)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.HttpRequestHandler.getURLConnection(HttpRequestHandler.java:233)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.HttpRequestHandler.connect(HttpRequestHandler.java:124)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.Downloader.connect(Downloader.java:151)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.Downloader.connect(Downloader.java:24)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.HttpRequestHandler.connect(HttpRequestHandler.java:117)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.Downloader.connect(Downloader.java:146)
at com.install4j.gui.c.h.c(ejt:72)
at com.install4j.gui.c.h.run(ejt:38)
```

This runs contrary to the following two assumptions:
1) install4j should record the proxy settings.
2) install4j should show a proxy dialog with these settings.
What did I miss?

UPDATE: `-DproxyAuth=false` would change the error message, it would now complain about certificate problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This concerns the JRE downloads in the install4j IDE and will be fixed in 7.0.7.

Please write to support@ej-technologies.com to get a build that contains the fix.

Alternatively, you can download JRE bundles manually from

https://download.ej-technologies.com/bundles/list

Comment: No sweat, it looks like we can wait (until everything gets repriorized again, of course ;-) )